# Spritekit: Animate node with running atlas and move node

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, jquery-animate

I want animate a character as running using .atlas and simultaneously also move the character on screen. 
I was able to simulate running using atlas but don't know how to simultaneously move it.
Right now I use this:

```
let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames, timePerFrame: 0.2)
```

`monsterNode.runAction((animation))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, for instance, apply force to the node's physicsBody. This is great for a platformer, as obstacles and the landmark would slow down the character, making it more realistic.

```
let force = CGVector(dx: 9000, dy: 0)
self.physicsBody?.applyForce(force)
```

For a space racer or other more simple movement, you could simply apply `velocity` to it.

```
self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 100, dy:10)
```

See [SKPhysicsBody reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody) for more.

**Update:**
For a very simple movement, you can use the SKAction's [moveBy](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417739-move) and [moveTo](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417768-move) methods and [group](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417688-group) the movement and the animation.

```
let vector = CGVector(dx:100, dy: 10)
let moveAction = SKAction.move(by: vector, duration: 1)
yourNode.run(SKAction.group([moveAction, animationAction])
```

Comment: Instead of using force or velocity. Is there a way to use moveBy along with my animation. I just want him to move few pixels per run action.

Comment: Well, of course you have the SKAction's [moveBy](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417739-move) and [moveTo](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417768-move)

Comment: Thanks Adam for taking time and answering the question. I tried: yourNode.run(SKAction([moveAction, animationAction]). It looks good but only issue is its a sequence. It will move the character first and then run the animation of running. I somehow want these two together, so that when he is running, he is actually moving on the screen.

Comment: Try `yourNode.run(SKAction.group([moveAction, animationAction])`, I edited the answer as well.